# Modifying EmguCV to add a missing function using P/Invoke

Tags: c#, opencv, pinvoke, kinect, emgucv

It has been a month now while I am making a robot that would explore an unknown area and would make a 3D map using the Kinect sensor.

As I am a C# developer, I am using EmguCV as a wrapper to the OpenCV library to use its functions for the computer vision.

For a certain purpose I would like to use the "estimateAffine3D" function provided by OpenCV but it has not been added to EmguCV yet. Therefore I thought of using "P/Invoke" calls to use the function the way Emgu does it. I opened the source of Emgu, found the CvInvoke class and the calib3d class. In that I added the function like this:

```
  [DllImport(OPENCV_CALIB3D_LIBRARY, CallingConvention = CvInvoke.CvCallingConvention)]
  [return: MarshalAs(CvInvoke.BoolToIntMarshalType)]
  public static extern bool cvEstimateAffine3D(
     IntPtr srcpt,
     IntPtr dstpt,
     out IntPtr outp,
     out IntPtr outliers,
     double ransacThreshold = 3.0f,
     double confidence = 0.99f);
```

(Sorry for any obvious errors: I am just a newbie at P/Invoking)

The thing won't work at all. If a put a breakpoint on it and visual studio hits it, it would't stop at the breakpoint, just continue!

Please help!
Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks!

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up using a library called Mobile Robotics Programming Toolkit, and made a C++/CLI wrapper to expose functions to c#...

Answer (score 1):

Affine3d Estimation has [been recently added](http://sourceforge.net/p/emgucv/code/ci/8c182459636f9534d9c86b574be56d2575d98c67/) to git emgucv repository (you can find it in cvInvokeCvExtern.cs).

Otherwise if you want to extend your current emgucv version you can p/invoke it using this:

```
[DllImport(EXTERN_LIBRARY, CallingConvention = CvInvoke.CvCallingConvention, EntryPoint = "CvEstimateAffine3D")] 
internal extern static int  _CvEstimateAffine3D(IntPtr src, IntPtr dst, IntPtr affineEstimate, IntPtr inliers, double ransacThreshold, double confidence);
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome reply but it gives me an error: "Unable to find an entry point named 'CvEstimateAffine3D' in DLL 'cvextern'." Any ideas? :-(

Comment: Okay so I got rid of that error by using dumpbin and using the entry point directly. The current code is:

`[DllImport(OPENCV_CALIB3D_LIBRARY, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "?estimateAffine3D@cv@@YAHAEBV_InputArray@1@0AEBV_OutputArray@1@1NN@Z")]
        internal extern static int _CvEstimateAffine3D(IntPtr src, IntPtr dst, IntPtr affineEstimate, IntPtr inliers, double ransacThreshold, double confidence);`

It gives me this error: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Any ideas?

Comment: My reply refers to the latest git code, if you use it estimateAffine3d can be used through
cvextern calls (behind the scenes this functions are as you find out inside calib3d).
If you want to stay with your current emgu version your approach seems fine but I think that your "Attempted to read or write memory"  error could depends on wrong way of pass parameters, try passing params using out keyword: CvInvoke.CvEstimateAffine3D(srcPts, dstPts, out estimate, out inlier, 3, 0.99).